# Should I bother unit testing my repository layer

Tags: unit-testing

Just putting this one out for debate really.

I get unit testing. Sometimes feels time consuming but I'm all for the benefits.

I've an application set up that contains a repository layer and a service layer, using IoC, and I've been unit testing the methods.

Now I know the benefits of isolating my methods for unit testing so there is little or no dependency on other methods.

The question I've got is this. If I only ever access my repository methods through my service layer methods would **only** testing the service layers not be good enough? I'm testing against a test database.

Could it not be considered an extension of the idea that you only need to test your public methods? Maybe I'm just trying to skip some testing ;)

Comment: This sounds like you are testing your service layer and repository layer together. I am correct in this? If so, you should be mocking the repository layer and then testing it independently.

Comment: @Kim R I am currently testing them independently at the moment using mocks etc. I'm fine with all that, my question is if I never access them directly why test them seperately

Comment: One advantage is that if one of your tests ever fails, the smaller the coverage of each individual test, the quicker you can isolate the issue.

Comment: I'm all for granular tests. But if a service layer test fails it would take all of 2 minutes to isolate the problem as the repository. That offset against the time required to create mocks and fakes?

Comment: https://rbcs-us.com/documents/Why-Most-Unit-Testing-is-Waste.pdf

Answer (score 23):

Yes, you should test your repository layer. Although the majority of these tests fall into a different classification of tests. I usually refer to them as integration tests to distinguish them from my unit tests. The difference being that there is an external dependency on a resource (your database) and that these tests will likely take much longer to run.

The primary reason for testing your repositories separately is that you'll be testing different things. The repository is responsible for handling translation and interaction with whatever persistence store you're using. The service layer, on the other hand, is responsible for coordinating your various respositories and other dependencies into functionality that represents business logic, which likely involves more than just a relay to a repository method and in some instances may involve multiple calls to multiple repositories.

First, to clarify the service layer testing - when testing the service layer, the repositories should be mocked so that they are isolated from what you're testing in the service layer. As you pointed out in your comment, this gives you a more granular level of testing and isolates the code under test. Your unit tests will also run much faster now because there are no database connections slowing them down.

Now, here are a few advantages of adding integration tests to your repositories...

1. It allows you to test out those pieces of code as you're writing them, a la TDD.
2. It ensures that whatever persistence language you're using (SQL, HQL, serialized objects, etc.) is formulated correctly for the operation you're attempting to perform.
3. If you're using an object-relational mapper, it ensures that your mappings are defined correctly.
4. In the future, you may find that you need to support another type of persistence. Depending on how your repository tests are structured, you may be able to reuse a large number of the tests to verify that the new database schema works correctly. For repository methods that implement database specific logic, obviously you'll have to create separate tests.
5. When coupled with Continuous Integration it's nice to have the repository tests separated. Integration tests, by nature take longer to run than unit tests. As such, they're usually run at less frequent intervals so that the immediate feedback available from running unit tests is not delayed.

Those are all advantages that I've seen in various projects that I've worked on. There may be more.

All that having been said, I will admit that I'm not as thorough with the repository integration tests as I am with unit tests. When it comes to testing an update on a particular object, for example, I'm usually content testing that one database column was successfully updated rather than creating a separate test for each individual column or a larger test that verifies every column in one test. For me, it depends on the complexity of the operation that the respository method is performing and whether there's any special condition that needs to be isolated.

Answer (score 8):

You should test your repository layer.  However if you have integration, story or system tests that cover it, then you can make a good case of not having unit tests as well.

Unit testing is great for complex stand-a-lone objects, but there is no point spending a long time writing unit tests for simple methods that are covered by “higher level” tests.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't this depend on how how smart the repository access layer is? If your repository takes parameters to filter (Linq to SQL for example) the given result set surely this logic will need to be tested.

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests: test an individual logic (a method) without worrying the dependency of that logic. Mostly falls in white box category.

Integration test: can test end to end flow or more than one layer together to ensure its correctness. Mostly falls in black box category.

In Dao most of the time there is no business logic, it just forms a query for a particular database implementation. So no need for a unit test if we already covered it in our integration test. Still, we can write unit tests for Dao if there is some logic in it.

As dao layers are so tightly coupled with database implementation, most of the time junit test for dao has become synonyms for testing of underlying databases.
The query we build can only be validated by the underlying Database engine.

I used to write unit tests (can call integration tests) for dao by using actual database or mocking  a database with a compatible database(follow the same sql standard ,for example mysql engine can be replaced by sqlite or in memory H2 database) and inject this database in dao for testing the dao layer and query build in that dao layer.

Answer (score -12):

> I get unit testing

Next step is Test Driven Development (TDD). It will answer your question.