# Setup Unit Test to test a controller using Unity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unit-testing, unity-container

I use Unity to create an instance of `CustomerService`. That's work for the code below in the ASP.NET MVC application.

When I create the ASP.NET MVC application I created the ASP.NET MVC test project. I'd like test the actions (here : `/Home/Index`).
The problem is I can't set `Unity`. I'd like create a real call to the action and no mocking.

Do you have an idea how setup in the test project ?  I tried this but I don't find the right syntax to create the instance of `CustomerService` to use as parameter when I call the controller.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Index()
{
    var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();

    //I don't find the right syntax for resolve
    ICustomerService customerService = container.Resolve??????

    HomeController controller = new HomeController(customerService);
    ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    container.Dispose();
}
```

Working code used in ASP.NET MVC application

```
namespace MyTestMVC
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ICustomerService _customerService;

        public HomeController(ICustomerService customerService)
        {
            _customerService = customerService;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var result = _customerService.MyMethod();
            //.....
            return View();
        }
    }
}

//I set Unity like this : 
namespace MyTestMVC.App_Start
{
    public class UnityConfig
    {
        private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            RegisterTypes(container);
            return container;
        });

        public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
        {
            return container.Value;
        }

        public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            container.RegisterType<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();
        }
    }
}

[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyTestMVC.App_Start.UnityWebActivator), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof(MyTestMVC.App_Start.UnityWebActivator), "Shutdown")]
namespace MyTestMVC.App_Start
{
    public static class UnityWebActivator
    {
        /// <summary>Integrates Unity when the application starts.</summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
            FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(FilterProviders.Providers.OfType<FilterAttributeFilterProvider>().First());
            FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider(container));
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
        }

        public static void Shutdown()
        {
            var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
            container.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're testing the action without mocking then you're not unit testing! Each 'unit' that you're testing should be 'the smallest testable part of an application'. I would never include anything to do with ioc/di in my unit tests

Comment: You are right @matt_lethargic, I rephrase .... "How test an action, completely without launch the browser ?"

Comment: Did any one found the solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
container.Resolve<ICustomerService>();
```

Answer (score 0):

"How test an action, completely without launch the browser ?"

Install Moq into your Unit test project.

```
install-package Moq
```

Then in your test create a moq instance of ICustomerService and stub the methods used

```
var mock = new Mock<ICustomerService>();
mock.Setup(x => x.MyMethod()).Returns(true);
```

Then pass in your mock object to an instance of the controller and then call the method on the controller

```
var controller = new HomeController(mock);
var result = controller.MyMethod();
```

Using Moq you can assert if methods have been called etc

Further reading:
https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Comment: Of course but I'd like really call the db, have the real view returned, real data and not fake data

Comment: This would then be almost an Integration Test as it relies on an external resource and not a Unit Test (You'll want to keep these in a different test project). This answer explains in more depth http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452928/should-i-bother-unit-testing-my-repository-layer

Comment: .... also forget using Unity in any tests. Create a new instance of the CustomerService class manually... var custService = new CustomerService etc