# How to set up database-heavy unit tests in Symfony2 using PHPUnit?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit

I am quite new to the world of testing and I want to make sure I am on the right track.

I am trying to setup unit tests in a *symfony2* project using *phpunit*.

*PHPUnit* is working and the simple default controller tests work fine. (Yet this is not about functional testing but unit testing my application.)

My project relies heavily on database interactions though, and as far as I understand from [phpunit's documentation](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html), I should set up a class based on `\PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase`, then create fixtures for my db and work from there.

Yet, *symfony2* only offers a `WebTestCase` class which only extends from `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` out of the box.

So am I right to assume that I should create my own `DataBaseTestCase` which mostly copies `WebTestCase`, only difference being that it extends from `\PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase` and implements all its abstract methods?

Or is there another "built-in" recommended workflow for *symfony2* concerning database-centric tests?

As I want to make sure that my models store and retrieve the right data, I do not want to end up testing the specifics of *doctrine* by accident.

Comment: I'm working through the same issue. Any luck so far?

Comment: @JasonSwett Nope. I just started a bounty due to lack of a satisfying answer.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/145163/457268

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr:

- If and only if you want to go the whole functional test route, then I recommend looking up [Sgoettschkes's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12508889/457268).
- If you want to unit test your application and have to test code that interacts with the database, either read on or jump directly to [symfony2 docs](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/testing/database.html)
   (There is a more up-to-date version also talking about [testing with fixtures for symfony5](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/database.html))

---

There were certain aspects in my original question that make it clear that my understanding of the differences between unit testing and functional tests was lacking. (As I have written I want to unit test the application, yet was also talking about Controller test at the same time; and those are functional test by defintion).

Unit testing only makes sense for services and not for repositories. And those services can use mocks of the entity manager. (I would even go as far as to say: If possible, write services that only expect entities to be passed into them. Then you only need to create mocks of those entities and your unit-tests of your business logic become very straightforward.)

My actual use case for my application was pretty well reflected on the symfony2 docs on [how to test code that interacts with the database](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/testing/database.html).

They provide this example for a service test:

Service class:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class SalaryCalculator
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function calculateTotalSalary($id)
    {
        $employeeRepository = $this->entityManager
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Employee');
        $employee = $employeeRepository->find($id);

        return $employee->getSalary() + $employee->getBonus();
    }
}
```

Service test class:

```
namespace Tests\AppBundle\Salary;

use AppBundle\Salary\SalaryCalculator;
use AppBundle\Entity\Employee;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class SalaryCalculatorTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testCalculateTotalSalary()
    {
        // First, mock the object to be used in the test
        $employee = $this->getMock(Employee::class);
        $employee->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getSalary')
            ->will($this->returnValue(1000));
        $employee->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getBonus')
            ->will($this->returnValue(1100));

        // Now, mock the repository so it returns the mock of the employee
        $employeeRepository = $this
            ->getMockBuilder(EntityRepository::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
        $employeeRepository->expects($this->once())
            ->method('find')
            ->will($this->returnValue($employee));

        // Last, mock the EntityManager to return the mock of the repository
        $entityManager = $this
            ->getMockBuilder(ObjectManager::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
        $entityManager->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getRepository')
            ->will($this->returnValue($employeeRepository));

        $salaryCalculator = new SalaryCalculator($entityManager);
        $this->assertEquals(2100, $salaryCalculator->calculateTotalSalary(1));
    }
}
```

No test database required for those kind of test, only mocking.

As it is important to test the business logic, not the persistence layer.

Only for functional tests does it make sense to have its own test database that one should build and tear down afterwards, and the big question should be:

When do functional test make sense?

I used to think that *test all the things* is the right answer; yet after working with lots of legacy software that in itself was barely test-driven developed I have become a bit more <s>lazy</s>pragmatic and consider certain functionality as working until proven otherwise by a bug.

Assume I have an application that parses an XML, creates an object out of it, and stores those objects into a database. If the logic that stores the objects to the database is known to work (as in: the company requires the data and is, as of yet, not broke), and even if that logic is a big ugly pile of crap, there is no *imminent* need to test that. As all I need to make sure that my XML parser extracts the right data. I can infer from experience that the right data will be stored.

There are scenarios where functional test are quite important, i.e. if one were to write an online shop. There it would be business critical that bought items get stored into the database and here functional tests with the whole test database make absolute sense.

Answer (score 35):

I have never used the `PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase`, mostly because for these two reasons:

- It doesn't scale well. If you set up and tear down the database for every single test and you have a application which relies heavily on the database, you end up creating and dropping the same schema over and over again.
- I like to have my fixtures not only within my tests but also within my development database and some fixtures are even needed for production (initial admin user or product categories or whatever). Having them inside an xml which can only be used for phpunit doesn't seem right to me.

**My way in theory...**

I use the [doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle) for fixtures (no matter what purpose) and set up the whole database with all fixtures. I then execute all tests against this database and make sure to recreate the database if a test changed it.

The advantages are that I don't need to set up a database again if a test only reads but don't change anything. For changes I have to do drop it and create it again or make sure to revert the changes.

I use sqlite for testing because I can set up the database, then copy the sqlite file and replace it with a clean one to bring back the original database. That way I don't have to drop the database, create it and load all fixtures again for a clean database.

**...and in code**

I wrote an [article about how I do database tests with symfony2 and phpunit](http://sgoettschkes.blogspot.com/2012/06/symfony2-test-database-best-pratice.html).

Although it uses sqlite I think one can easily make the changes to use MySQL or Postgres or whatever.

**Thinking further**

Here are some other ideas which might work:

- I once read about a test setup where before you use the database you start a transaction (within the setUp method) and then use the tearDown to rollback. That way you don't need to set up the database again and just need to initialize it once.
- My setup described above has the drawback that the database is set up every time phpunit is executed, even if you only run some unit tests with no database interaction. I am experimenting with a setup where I use a global variable which indicates if the database was set up and then within the tests call a method whcih checks this variable and initializes the database if it didn't happened yet. That way only when a tests needs the database the setup would happen.
- One problem with sqlite is that it doesn't work the same as MySQL in some rare cases. I had an issue once where something behaved different in MySQL and sqlite causing a test to fail when in with MySQL everything worked. I cannot remember what it was exactly.

Comment: There is a bundle that provides further integration between PHPUnit and Doctrine's fixtures called [Liip/FunctionalTestBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle). We use this in combination with a sqlite database defined in our config_test.yml configuration and it helps to simplify things a lot! One really useful feature of the bundle is that it can cache your sqlite database so the database isn't shared between tests with reduced overheads involved in creating and setting up the database for each test.

Comment: Regarding the differences between SQLite and MySQL, I think the first things that you run into are date and time functions like NOW() that do not work in SQLite. I have a recent post in my blog about using SQLite for unit testing that describes some of these issues http://cvuorinen.net/2012/10/model-testing-using-sqlite-in-memory-database-with-zend-framework/

Comment: [Here's](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2011/10/symfony2-use-a-bootstrap-file-for-your-phpunit-tests-and-run-some-console-commands/) another nice article showing how to work with Doctrine and Symfony for testing

Answer (score -1):

You can use this class:

```
<?php

namespace Project\Bundle\Tests;

require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/../../../app/AppKernel.php';

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool;

abstract class TestCase extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
/**
* @var Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\AppKernel
*/
protected $kernel;

/**
 * @var Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
 */
protected $entityManager;

/**
 * @var Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container
 */
protected $container;


public function setUp()
{
    // Boot the AppKernel in the test environment and with the debug.
    $this->kernel = new \AppKernel('test', true);
    $this->kernel->boot();

    // Store the container and the entity manager in test case properties
    $this->container = $this->kernel->getContainer();
    $this->entityManager = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();

    // Build the schema for sqlite
    $this->generateSchema();


    parent::setUp();
}

public function tearDown()
{
    // Shutdown the kernel.
    $this->kernel->shutdown();

    parent::tearDown();
}

protected function generateSchema()
{
    // Get the metadatas of the application to create the schema.
    $metadatas = $this->getMetadatas();

    if ( ! empty($metadatas)) {
        // Create SchemaTool
        $tool = new SchemaTool($this->entityManager);
        $tool->createSchema($metadatas);
    } else {
        throw new Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException('No Metadata Classes to process.');
    }
}

/**
 * Overwrite this method to get specific metadatas.
 *
 * @return Array
 */
protected function getMetadatas()
{
    return $this->entityManager->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();
}
}
```

And then you can test your entity. Something like this (assuming you have a entity User)

```
//Entity Test
class EntityTest extends TestCase {

    protected $user;

    public function setUp()
    {
         parent::setUp();
         $this->user = new User();
         $this->user->setUsername('username');
         $this->user->setPassword('p4ssw0rd');


         $this->entityManager->persist($this->user);
         $this->entityManager->flush();

    }

    public function testUser(){

         $this->assertEquals($this->user->getUserName(), "username");
         ...

    }

}
```

Hope this help.

Source: theodo.fr/blog/2011/09/symfony2-unit-database-tests

Comment: Why you no give the Reference http://www.theodo.fr/blog/2011/09/symfony2-unit-database-tests/